# Mysql: how to structure this data and search it

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I'm new to mysql. Right now, I have this kind of structure in mysql database:

```
| keyID | Param           | Value
| 123   | Location        | Canada
| 123   | Cost            | 34
| 123   | TransportMethod | Boat
 ...
 ...
```

I have probably like 20 params with unique values for each Key ID. I want to be able to search in mysql given the 20 params with each of the values and figure out which keyID.

Firstly, how should I even restructure mysql database? Should I have 20 param columns + keyID?
Secondly, (relates to first question), how would I do the query to find the keyID?

Comment: Your question says you have a unique value for each KeyID, but your sample data shows '123' as the keyID for each row--is that a mistake?

Comment: i'm assuming you're able to dynamically generate your SQL in whatever programming language you're using... is this true?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really have enough context to answer your question properly.  Are you saying that you want to fetch all the param/value pairs for a given keyID?

Comment: @Flimzy - he has unique values 'Cost', 'Location', 'TransportMethod' for each key '123', not that 123 is unique. I think that's what he means

Comment: recursive nasty sql built up with a programming language:  
    select keyid from params WHERE Location='Canada' and exists(select keyid from params where param='Cost' and value < 50)...  keep wrapping for each param - something like that. i believe i'm 'off' in my exists clause. i always have to look that up.

Comment: I am able to generate the sql using perl, so it's true

Comment: the keyID is unique for  each group of (20 params, 20 values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your params are identical across different keys (or all params are a subset of some set of params that the objects may have), you should structure the database so that each column is a param, and the row corresponds to one KeyID and the values of its params.

```
|keyID|Location|Cost|TransportMethod|...|...
|123  |Canada  |34  |Boat ...
|124  | ...
 ...
```

Then to query for the keyID you would use a SELECT, FROM, and WHERE statement, such as,

```
SELECT keyID
FROM key_table 
WHERE Location='Canada'
AND Cost=34
AND TransportMethod='Boat'
...
```

for more info see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp

edit: if your params change across different objects (keyIDs) this will require a different approach I think

Comment: I see your point. I was thinking of this. My original method was also for readability of the data ...

Comment: this is definitely one possibility, i just hope you don't have to add attributes frequently :( - definitely easier to implement and sometimes simple is best.

Comment: The most commonly perceived "downside" to this approach is the "But what if I have a lot of NULL columns this way"? But in practically all DB engines these days, NULL columns are very cheap, so they don't really waste space or other overhead.  This is the approach I would suggest, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The design you show is called Entity-Attribute-Value.  It breaks many rules of relational database design, and it's very hard to use with SQL.

In a relational database, you should have a separate column for each attribute type.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  keyID           SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Location        VARCHAR(20),
  Cost            NUMERIC(9,2),
  TransportMethod VARCHAR(10)
);
```

Comment: i think you just answered my question!

Answer (score 0):

I agree that Nick's answer is probably best, but if you *really* want to keep your key/value format, you could accomplish what you want with a view (this is in PostgreSQL syntax, because that's what I'm familiar with, but the concept is the same for MySQL):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myview AS
SELECT keyID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Param = 'Location' THEN Value END) AS Location,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Param = 'Cost' THEN Value END) AS Cost,
    ....
FROM mytable;
```

Performance here is likely to be dismal, but if your queries are not frequent, it could get the job done.

Comment: A similar view would work in MySQL, but using `CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS` syntax.  One should use either `GROUP BY keyID` or `WHERE keyID=123` if the params table contains params for more than one keyID.